# I am trying to convert all the .bin files in a folder to .txt files in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to convert all the .bin files in a folder to .txt file in Python, 
This is what I tried

```
    import glob
    import errno
    path = 'Dir_path'
    files = glob.glob(path)
    for name in files:
       if name.endswith("bytes.bin"):

          with open(name) as f:

            data =  np.fromfile(f, np.uint32)
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
            np.savetxt(r'name', df.values, fmt='%d')
```

I want to save the each text file as the same name of the bin file.

How can i do that. I am new to coding, Please help me to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in:

```
            np.savetxt(r'name', df.values, fmt='%d')
```

All txt files are saved under the same filename `name`, and because of overwriting only the last file will be available on the disk.

You could change that to:

```
            np.savetxt( name.replace("bytes.bin", ".txt"), df.values, fmt='%d')
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable reply,
I tried that way, but as this line of code demands another line of code after, It threw 
"unexpected EOF while parsing" error. 
any suggestion?

Comment: There was a typo in my code: `name.replace("bytes.bin", ".txt"` -> `name.replace("bytes.bin", ".txt")`, missing the closing `)`. Should be fine now.